# Filtering Max 3 count using groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, max

I am working with a dataframe that contains 20K rows.
I created a sample dataframe as follow to replicate the data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['Team'] = ['A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2']
df ['Competition'] = ['L1','L1','L1','L1','L1','L1','L2','L2','L2','L2','L2','L2']
df ['Score_count'] = [2,1,3,4,7,8,1,5,8,5,7,1]
```

I would like to keep the rows where two maximum values of Score_count by using `groupby(['Competition','Team'])`

I am able to keep the rows with maximum Score_count by using transform(max) as follow:

```
idx = df.groupby(['Competition','Team'])['Score_count'].transform(max) == df['Score_count']
df = df[idx]
```

But what I wanted to do is to keep n numbers of maximum (in this case is two maximum values) Score_count for the same groupby.

How can I do it?

Below is my expected output:

```
       Team     Competition  Score_count
0       A1          L1             3
1       A1          L1             2
2       A2          L1             8
3       A2          L1             7
4       B1          L2             8
5       B1          L2             5
6       B2          L2             7
7       B2          L2             5
```

You may also refer to the picture below for the expected output:

[image]

Can anyone advise how to do it?
Thanks,

Zep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` *Team* and *Competition* and then take the two largest values with `.nlargest`:

```
df.groupby(['Team', 'Competition']).Score_count.nlargest(2).reset_index([0,1])

#   Team Competition  Score_count
#2    A1          L1            3
#0    A1          L1            2
#5    A2          L1            8
#4    A2          L1            7
#8    B1          L2            8
#7    B1          L2            5
#10   B2          L2            7
#9    B2          L2            5
```

To drop the original index:

```
df.groupby(['Team', 'Competition']).Score_count.nlargest(2).reset_index([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)

#  Team Competition  Score_count
#0   A1          L1            3
#1   A1          L1            2
#2   A2          L1            8
#3   A2          L1            7
#4   B1          L2            8
#5   B1          L2            5
#6   B2          L2            7
#7   B2          L2            5
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom, Appreciate your help. May I know the meaning of .reset_index([0,1]). I know that reset_index is for resetting index. How about the list [0,1]?

Comment: I did use nlargest before posting this question but I have got error. Therefore, I was find other solution. It looks I missed some part in nlargest. Thanks.

Comment: the list `[0,1]` specifies which index levels to reset. Since after grouping Team and Competition are set as the first and second index. Hence `[0,1]` here -

Comment: When I applied to my actual df. it showed me the following error:
**Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2**
my code is as follow:
data_score = data_score.groupby(['Round_Number', 'Competition', 'Date','Match','Score']).Score_count.nlargest(3).reset_index([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Do you get error by running `data_score.groupby(['Round_Number', 'Competition', 'Date','Match','Score']).Score_count.nlargest(3)` only?

Comment: Yeah. That was what I tried before I post this question.

Comment: What did the above give you? Does it error out? Also which pandas version are you using? It works fine for me on `0.23.4`.

Comment: I am using 0.23.3. I am not getting an error but all the groupby column has been eliminated and it did not filter max 3 values:
The df only contains  index and Score_count.

Comment: It works fine with the sample data that I provided. But not with the actual data that I am using for analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183597/discussion-between-zephyr-and-psidom).

Comment: Can you post `data_score.head(10).to_json()` here so I can double check for you? I'm not sure what is happening. Sounds like a data issue -